# MSVS alias error C2988 (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error C2988 in MS VS2017 while trying to compile this code:

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator<T> = typename T::iterator;
```

This is an example of B. Stroustrup book "The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition". Unfortunately VS is rejecting this code. I've read that this might be some kind of bug of Microsoft's compiler but the topic was from 2013 and I can't beleive that they hadn't fixed it yet. This is frustrating because I try to understand aliases in C++ and I don't know if the problem lies by my side or the compiler's side. Any help would be nice.

EDIT:
Thanks for quick answer. I changed template as you've suggested and it works:

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::iterator;

template <typename C, typename V>
std::vector<Iterator<C>> find_all(C & c, V v)
{
    std::vector<Iterator<C>> res;
    for (auto p = c.begin(); p != c.end(); ++p)
        if (*p == v)
            res.push_back(p);
    return res;
}
```

And test function:

```
void find_all_test()
{
    std::string m{ "Marry had a little lamb" };
    for (auto p : find_all(m, 'a'))
        if (*p != 'a')
            std::cerr << "Error!\n";
}
```

Do you know why is there such error in Stroustrup's book? Is this translation fault (I'm using polish translation because it was much cheaper than the original) or can anyone who has the original version of the book check if it occurs there (it is chapter 4.5.1.). I wasted one hour of my learning time trying to figure out what am I doing wrong. Thanks for solving my problem.

Comment: A [mcve] please. This doesn't cut it.

Comment: it should be `using Iterator = typename T::iterator;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is the same as other templates, but yours looks a bit like a partial specialization (which don't exist for type aliases), hence the compiler's confusion:

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator    = typename T::iterator;
//            ^^^ No <T> please!
```